# Rails 4: Checking coupon by ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to do a query in rails to check a discount cupom in ajax.
The Ajax is woking fine, but I'm getting a route problem:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) /app/payment/check_cupom?cupom=afdasdf

Can anyone give me a light? Thanks!

I have this:

## HTML

```
<input name="cupom" type="text" placeholder="" id="cupom">
<p id="cupomResponse"></p>
```

## AJAX

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        $('#cupom').on('blur', function() {
          var cupom = $("#cupom").val();
          $.ajax({
              url: '/app/payment/check_cupom?cupom=' + cupom, type: 'get', dataType: 'html',
              processData: false,
              success: function(data) {
                  if (data == "record_not_found") {
                      alert("Record not found");
                  }
                  else {
                      $("#cupomResponse").val(data);
                  }
              }
          });
      });
    });
</script>
```

## ROUTE

```
resources :payment do
      collection do
        post 'pay', :action => :pay
        get 'check_cupom', :action => :check_cupom
      end
    end
```

## CONTROLLER

```
def check_cupom
  @cupom = Coupon.find_by(name: params[:cupom])
  if @cupom.blank?
    render :text => "record_not_found"
  else
      discount = @cupom.price.gsub(/[^\d^\.]/, '')
      render :text => discount
  end
end
```

## SERVER LOG

> Started GET "/app/payment/check_cupom?cupom=adfafd" for 127.0.0.1 at
>   2017-06-23 11:35:21 -0300 AbstractController::ActionNotFound - The
>   action 'show' could not be found for App::PaymentController: –

Comment: unrelated, but why are you calling it `cupom`?

Comment: Sorry, language...

Comment: Yeah. I'm already tried the rails path :/

Comment: Can you post your server log?

Comment: Started GET "/app/payment/check_cupom?cupom=adfafd" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-23 11:35:21 -0300

AbstractController::ActionNotFound - The action 'show' could not be found for App::PaymentController:

Comment: You basically have no show-action if you read the logs

Answer (score 0):

I put the logic in show function and it works. I dont know wyy, once the rake routes show me that the url was correct.